# How to Close Excel application and workbook that is open and running in the background?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am running VBA code in Access that requires an Excel workbook to open in the background. It opens okay, and I have it set to be invisible. However, when I try to close the Excel workbook(application) with Access VBA, it remains open in the background.

Here is the code I am running to open the Excel Workbook.

```
Public Function OpenExcelFile(strFilePath As String) As Boolean

Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook

Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set myWorkbook = appExcel.Workbooks.Open("D:\NewUserSetup\NewUserSetup.xlsx")
appExcel.Visible = false
Pause (1)
myWorkbook.RefreshAll

Set appExcel = Nothing

Set myWorkbook = Nothing

End Function
```

Here is the code I have to close the workbook, but isn't working.

```
Public Function CloseExcelFile(strFilePath As String) As Boolean

Dim ExcelApp As Excel.Application
Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook

    myWorkbook("D:\NewUserSetup\NewUserSetup.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False

'Set ExcelApp = Nothing
Set myWorkbook = Nothing


End Function
```

Comment: Closing the workbook and closing the app are two separate steps.  `myWorkbook.Close ...` followed by `appExcel.Quit`

Comment: @chrisneilsen Now I am getting Run-time error '91' Object variable or Withblock variable not set. 

Public Function CloseExcelFile(strFilePath As String) As Boolean

    Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
    Dim myWorkbook As Excel.Workbook

myWorkbook.Close
appExcel.Quit


End Function